# How to retrieve custom server variables ASP to JSP

Tags: jsp, redirect, asp-classic, server-variables

I have two custom server variables that I can see on ASP page:
**"HTTP_ONE"** and **"HTTP_TWO"**
How can I retrieve these data on a JSP page when redirected from a classic ASP page? I don't want to use query string or form.

---

**Update**:

*ASP Page*

```vb
   <% 
  ' Send redirect
  Call Response.Redirect("yourjspURL?ssouserid=" & Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_SSOUSERID"))
   %>
```

*JSP Page*

```java
<%
    String sso = request.getParameter("ssouserid");
    out.println(sso);  
%>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you pull headers in [jsp](/questions/tagged/jsp) like this;

```java
<%= request.getHeader("HTTP_ONE") %>
```

<strike>Remember though you will need to manually set these headers in your classic asp response before the redirect is called. Something like;</strike>

```vb
<%
' Pass-through two custom headers before response is sent.
Call Response.AddHeader("HTTP_ONE", Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_ONE"))
Call Response.AddHeader("HTTP_TWO", Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_TWO"))
' Send response
Call Response.Redirect("yourjspurl")
%>
```

---

**Update:**

After realising this wouldn't work due to the server sending a `HTTP 301 Found` to the client the only thing I can suggest is passing the header values as a querystring

```vb
Call Response.Redirect("yourjspurl?http_one=" & Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_ONE"))
```

Comment: @user3319282 I would use something like [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) to test that your headers are getting set in your response to the [tag:jsp] page, if they are the `null` is another issue.

Comment: @user3319282 If you have tested this could you post some of your code in your original question so I can help you further?

Comment: @user3319282 First try a simplier test in your [tag:asp-classic] page `Call Response.AddHeader("HTTP_ONE", "test value")` and see if you can see that value (recommend using [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) ideal for debugging issues like this)

Comment: ASP:
    `<%' Add custom header
          Call Response.AddHeader("HTTP_SSOUSERID", Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_SSOUSERID"))
        ' Send response
          Call Response.Redirect("http://localhost:8080/xxxx/testJSP.jsp")
        %>`
    
    JSP:  
    
        `<%
         String sso = request.getHeader("HTTP_SSOUSERID");    
         out.println(sso);
        %>`

Comment: @user3319282 I take it you've tested outputting `Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_SSOUSERID")` on your [tag:asp-classic] page first before redirecting?

Comment: yes. On ASP page I can see every server variables, tested.

Comment: It's fine. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @user3319282 What did you end up with in the end?